# The New List View Items not Clickable

Tags: android, listview

I am extremely new in android .I am making a list view ,and every time i click on a list's item  it shows the second list view but all items on the second list view are not clickable . I have tried all solutions to make items in the second list clickable but non of them worked for me .
Here is my code so far :

Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] boundryitems = {"Boundry Wall","Front Elevation","Corridor","Kitchen","Bedroom1"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Boundry List Adapter

        final ArrayAdapter boundry_Item1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_main,R.id.texti, boundryitems);
        ListView listView11 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvi);
        listView11.setAdapter(boundry_Item1);


        listView11.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);

                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 4) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 5) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 6) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 7) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

item 1 (With contains the second Listview) :

```
 public class item1 extends Activity {

        String[] snaglistciv = {"Paint","Garbage Room","Pump Room","Lights","Joint"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.snag_item);

    //Snag List Adapter

            final ArrayAdapter adapterSnag_Item = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.snag_item,R.id.textsnag, snaglistciv);

            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listsnag);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterSnag_Item);



            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    if (position == 0) {


                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), camerapic.class);

                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }
                    if (position == 1) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), camerapic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }

                    if (position == 2) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), camerapic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }

                    if (position == 3) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), camerapic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }

                    if (position == 4) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), camerapic.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }

                    if (position == 5) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }

                    if (position == 6) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }

                    if (position == 7) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), item1.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: First thing, If you are new at `Android`, Get used to use `recyclerView`.

Comment: is there any ImageButton or Button in adapter?

Comment: Starting same Activity on click of ListView items. then why using if-else ?

Comment: send all xml file

Answer (score 0):

Your activity's contentView and listview's item view are same??? `R.layout.snag_item`

```
        setContentView(R.layout.snag_item);

        final ArrayAdapter adapterSnag_Item = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.snag_item,R.id.textsnag, snaglistciv);
```